# Compile error when setting class in VBA

Tags: class, excel, compiler-errors, vba

I copied code from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/92204/A-quick-simple-VBA-FIFO-Queue-Implementation) but I'm getting an error when trying to run the code.

The problem would be in:

`Public NextItem As New queueItem`

and the error message is:

`user-defined type not defined`

Is my VBA version not right to do this or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/347662/A-quick-simple-VBA-FIFO-Queue-Implementation)? The one you provided has the alternative implementation (with arrays, not with references).

I got it to work for me. Steps:

- Right click on the VBA project file name, and go to `Insert-> Class Module`:

[image]

- Click `F4`. The `Properties` window appears. Then go to the class `Name` and change it to `Queue`:

[image]

- Copy and Paste the `Queue Class` code you found at the web site. Repeat the previous and this step for the `QueueItem` class (i.e., insert a `Class Module`, name it `QueueItem` and copy the code inside that class module).
- This time, insert a `Module` using the same process (not a `Class Module`, but rather a simple `Module`). You do not need to give your module a name, `Module1` will be OK.
- Copy the `Sub TestQueue()` inside the module and run it. It should work. If you use `Option Explicit` on your module, you will get an error that `element` is undefined. So we need to define it: `Dim element as Variant`, under the first few `Dim` statements of the subroutine. Then it should run.

The above worked for me, let me know if I can be more precise, or send the file to you.

Comment: The OP visited after this answer was posted and did not say "This did not work" so I assume this was a good answer but the OP was too lazy to say thank you or accept the answer.